# Is file IOstream OK to be initialized every loop?

Tags: java, performance, io

```
FileOutputStream st = null;

for(file_path:file_list)
{
 st = new FileOutputStream(file_path);
.
.
.

}
st.close();
```

What I was wondering about was
if I didn't close one stream and initialize it with new instance, does it affect the program performance?

If it does, is it because close() at the last line only closes last created stream and other previous ones are waiting for GC to clear themselves?

Thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: Dude - always "close" what you "open"!  Bad things could happen otherwise: garbled/truncated data, potential resource leaks, etc. etc. Also: you should familiarize yourself with Java [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over a list of filepaths. You should definitely create a new `FileOutputStream` per filepath. And you should also close each `OutputStream`. I would **strongly** recommend you use [`try-with-Resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead of manually closing (and wrap your stream with a `BufferedOutputStream`). Like,

```
for (String file_path : file_list) // I assume it's String(s)
{
    // Limit the stream visibility and program to OutputStream interface
    try (OutputStream st = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file_path))) {
        // ...
    }
}
```